# asp.net to MySql issue. Trying to return information from input

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, return, parameter-passing

When I try to call a string with asp.net such as `e7af78997ef220a557c97a1a4c11e0c2` the return always comes back null. I know for a fact it isn't null (all ID's are in that format or in an IP format). and it works when I input an int column.

So my problem is that The return is always null, and Visual Studio says

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

I know it has to do with `MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from a3bans.bans where GUID = '" + ban.GuidOrIP + "' ; ", conDataBase);` and I'm almost positive it has to do with

```
'" + ban.GuidOrIP + "' ; ", conDataBase);`
```

I think I've tried a million ways and and either have gotten syntax errors or `Null`

I think the issue has to do with the Database input rather than output. Input as in "select" I put in the ID just using a regular query and it populated the information, however. When trying to use my tban (the { getter; Setter;} it just returns Null...

Everything that I have researched has referenced to a button with .Text and nothing seems to help with a getter and setter.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("A3Bans/searchBan")]
        public string oSearchBan(tBan ban)
        {
            {
                tBan bans = new tBan();
                string dbConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=admin;password=00000";
                MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
                MySqlDataReader dbReader;
                MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from a3bans.bans where GUID = '" + ban.GuidOrIP + "' ; ", conDataBase); // Returning a null value?!

                conDataBase.Open();
                dbReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    tBan searchBan = new tBan();
                    searchBan.GuidOrIP = dbReader.GetString("GUID");
                    searchBan.BanType = dbReader.GetString("BanType");
                    searchBan.BanReason = dbReader.GetString("Reason");
                    searchBan.Proof = dbReader.GetString("Proof");
                    bans = searchBan;
                }
                dbReader.Close();
                return bans.Proof;
            }
        }
```

If I replace the query string with string `selectQuery = "Select * FROM a3bans.bans WHERE BanID=" + int.Parse(schBanID.Text);` It will return the proper values from the client side. and If i were to translate it to the API it alreturns the correct values. But it is an int and not a string.

UPDATE:
I used which only works on int values but not a string.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("A3Bans/searchBan")]
        public string oSearchBan(tBan ban)
        {
            {
                tBan bans = new tBan();
                string dbConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=admin;password=0000";
                MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
                MySqlDataReader dbReader;
                conDataBase.Open();

                // Returns a null value from bans.Proof
                // If placing a /w real GUID without null fields, rather than "ban.GuidOrIP" , the return populates properly. 
                // and works with int
                // Either Null or Invalid Syntax...
                MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM a3bans.bans WHERE (BanID) LIKE (@BanID)", conDataBase);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BanID", ban.BanID);
                selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This works with int... but still doesn't work with a string... what the heck do I do to get it to work with a text/numerical string?

Comment: I don't see where you ever assign a value to bans.GuidOrIP.  You create a new instance of the class with tBan bans = new tBan(), but you never set the value.   Try setting bans.GuidOrIp = Convert.ToInt32(schBanId.Text).  Your schBanId textbox must have a value or that will fail if you dont have any logic checking for empty text box.

Comment: `schBanId.Text` is referenced in the client side.. the API won't register it. and vice versa.

I'm using Postman to post in it so there technically isn't an empty box when I try to return the value.

Have also tried Client side and it's the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("A3Bans/searchBan")]
        public string oSearchBan(tBan ban)
        {
            {
                tBan bans = new tBan();
                string dbConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=admin;password=00000";
                MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
                MySqlDataReader dbReader;

//<Changes>
                MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from a3bans.bans where [GUID] =@prmGuid  ", conDataBase); // Returning a null value?!

                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmGuid", new Guid(ban.GuidOrIP));

//</Changes end>
                conDataBase.Open();
                dbReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    tBan searchBan = new tBan();
                    searchBan.GuidOrIP = dbReader.GetString("GUID");
                    searchBan.BanType = dbReader.GetString("BanType");
                    searchBan.BanReason = dbReader.GetString("Reason");
                    searchBan.Proof = dbReader.GetString("Proof");
                    bans = searchBan;
                }
                dbReader.Close();
                return bans.Proof;


            }
        }
```

Comment: ` "ExceptionMessage": "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: g",` what the heck is parameter "g"?

Comment: `new Guid.(ban.GuidOrIP));` is where the g parameter is coming from, from System.Guid.

Comment: You need to make sure, a valid value is being passed to new Guid(YourValue), otherwise it gonna throw error.

Comment: sigh... null null null or syntax error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'equals _binary 'A3Bans.Schemas.tGuid'' at line 1",``

U had to make a new class with a constructor, but it still returns null... I don't understand why.